# Sed match after quotes

Tags: bash, sed

Using `sed` on `bash` how can I match string after quotes?

```
"Foo"BA_R
```

and

```
"Foo"BAR
```

And only get `BA_R` and `BAR`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ echo '"Foo"BA_R' | sed  's,.*",,'
BA_R
$ echo '"Foo"BAR' | sed  's,.*",,'
BAR
```

It's also a good jub for `cut`:

```
$ echo '"Foo"BA_R'  | cut -d'"' -f3
BA_R
$ echo '"Foo"BAR'  | cut -d'"' -f3
BAR
```

Comment: Works great for both. Thanks!

Comment: Or `grep -o '[^"]*$'`, which would actually do what the user asks about, i.e. "match the string after the quotes".